# Using coordinates in ionic LaunchNavigator.navigate instead of city text

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework

i'm trying to load a navigator app from my ionic application to show directions and i am using google maps, but the problem is that i am using the launchNavigator function which only accepts a string - the name of the location.

```
navigateLocation(){
    let options: LaunchNavigatorOptions = {
        start:[this.latitude,this.longitude],
        app: this.launchNavigator.APP.GOOGLE_MAPS
    };
    this.launchNavigator.navigate('Lagos, ON', options)  //here
    .then(success =>{
        console.log(success);
    },error=>{
        console.log(error);
    })
}
```

so the Lagos option, could be london, or any other city, but what if i'm trying to get a remote location, or some other city. 
why cant i just use the longitude and latitude, instead of the name.. 
for example

```
this.launchNavigator.navigate({lat:8.234345, lng:7:5644563}, 'ON', options);
```

something similar to that....

i dont know if anyone has done this before, please help. 
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use it like this
 `let destination = [lat, lng];
    this.launchNavigator.navigate(destination)
      .then(
        success => console.log('Launched navigator'),
        error => console.log('Error launching navigator', error)
      );`

And it shows me how do i go from where I am to the coordinates I pass.

Comment: I have got this error
"ERROR TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at LaunchNavigator.navigate ..."
Please help me to solve this

Comment: Did you import LaunchNavigator above and put public launchNavigator:LaunchNavigator and used like this.launchNavigator

Comment: @SANAAbdoulAziz

Comment: Yes, already import LaunchNavigator and i have put public launchNavigator:LaunchNavigator in constructor and this.launchNavigator.navigate ...
But i am using ionic 4.6.0 mean ionic 4 beta so i think that is the problem